# Range of answer: Least squares problem in a case of a rank deficient system

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am new to Algebra and I need some clarification in terms of column and row space and LS solution.

Considering the linear system of Ax=b;
In case of A is an over-determined and not full rank matrix, we want to solve this system through minimizing LS problem. If we take the x* as the minimizer, could you please explain why "x* ∈ Range (A*)" ?

I think the explanation lies within the normal equation "A* Ax* = A*b". But I am not sure how should I explain the answer. in Particular, when I try to understand the question graphically, it becomes more complicated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Amirhossein Khademi, please accept the answer if it addresses your question, or comment if it does not.

Answer (score 1):

> explain why "x* ∈ Range (A*)"

**Short answer**

You are probably taking this statement out of context, where the statement was followed by "without loss of generality". It is *not true* that any least squares solutions belongs to the row space. It is *true* that we can assume (for some purposes) that the least squares solution belongs to the row space, *without loss of generality*. Here is a step-by-step explanation for you.

**Long answer**

For an overdetermined *full-rank* problem, $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m>n$, $\exists(\boldsymbol{A}^{*}\boldsymbol{A})^{-1}$, the least squares solution $x_+\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is in the row space $\mathrm{Range}\boldsymbol{A}^{*}$, because any vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is in the row space. The row space spans the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is a consequence of $\boldsymbol{A}$ being full column rank.

Now if you have an overdetermined *rank-deficient* problem, $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m>n$, $\not\exists(\boldsymbol{A}^{*}\boldsymbol{A})^{-1}$, then $\mathrm{Range}\boldsymbol{A}^{*}$ spans a proper subpace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

A very important theorem in linear algebra says that the row space of any matrix is an orthogonal complement to the nullspace (and vice versa): $(\mathrm{Range}\boldsymbol{A}^*)^\perp=\mathrm{Null}\boldsymbol{A}$.

In our case, this means that you can add an arbitrary vector from the nullspace $x_{0}\in\mathrm{Null}\boldsymbol{A}$ to a solution $x_+$ and obtain another solution $x_1=x_++x_0$, which will be almost as good. Conversely, any solution $x_1$ is uniquely decomposed into the sum $x_1=x_++x_0$, and you can remove the nullspace component $x_0$. The remaining $x_+$ will belong to $\mathrm{Range}\boldsymbol{A}^{*}$.

**Remark**

One important remark pertains to what the least squares problem is precisely. Some authors define it as $\|\boldsymbol{Ax}-\boldsymbol{b}\|_{2}^{2}\to\min$, which may have multiple solutions, all equal up to the nullspace component. Other authors require, in addition, that the solution has the minimal $\ell^2$ norm: $\|x\|_2\to\min$, subject to $\|\boldsymbol{Ax}-\boldsymbol{b}\|_{2}^{2}=\min$, in which case the solution is always unique and given by $x_+:=\boldsymbol{A}^+b$, where $\boldsymbol{A}^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $\boldsymbol{A}$. To avoid ambiguity, the latter problem formulation is called the minimum-length least squares.